Display Conky folder size as a bar
I display the /boot folder with this function
    ${execi 60 du -sh /boot | awk '{ print $1 }'}

That gives me the
168M    /boot

Now I would like to display this as a bar with "execbar".
But this only shows me an empty bar.
Is that even possible?

Your command should give you 168M not 168M    /boot, are you sure the /boot is included, despite your awk?

Yes, I entered this in the terminal.
sorry...

Please add all information to the question. The error you mentioned is about permissions, but you would get the same error with your current command. If you tried my solution and it didn't work, add the exact command you ran to your question.

You can, but you need a script that can express the size as a percentage. The execbar documentation reads:

${execbar(height),(width)command}
Same as exec, except if the first value returned is a value between 0-100, it will use that number to draw a horizontal bar. The height and width parameters are optional, and default to the default_bar_height and default_bar_width config settings, respectively.

So it assumes that it is being given a number between 1 and 100l, where 100 represents the full bar. So you need to pick a maximum size, and then show the current size as a percentage of that. Not sure how useful that would be, but you can't have a bar without a maximum size, it would just be a line of arbitrary length.
So, with your example, say we set the maximum to 300M. You can use this script:
#!/bin/sh

dir=$1
max=$2
size=$(du -sh "$dir" | sed -E 's/^([0-9]*).*/\1/') 
echo "$size * 100 / $max" | bc


The script takes a target directory as the first argument, and the maximum size as the second, and once you make it executable with chmod +x /path/to/script.sh, you can add it to your conky config with:
    ${execbar 10,300 60 /path/to/script.sh /boot 300}

Or, since you are using execi to run your du every minute, you might prefer execibar:
    ${execibar 60 10,300 60 /path/to/script.sh /boot 300}


Inserting the code does not work.

@barand3 for the third time: please add all this to your question! What exact code did you insert? How did it not work? What have you done? Did you create the script? Did you make it executable? Please EDIT your question and explain what you did.
